# How to Show battery icon and Wifi icon in fullscreen mode in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-intent, android-fragments

I am  developing a enterprise android application  (my android application that will be used by 500 users and  only my application need to be worked in that android tablet ) , When I made the UI to work in full screen mode, the  Battery icon and WiFi icon is hided , I don't want  to hide battery icon and WiFi icon(if connected to WiFi- the WiFi  icon must be shown ) when the UI is in full screen mode.

FULL SCREEN UI was achieved by using below code in my "onCreate" method of my activity

```
           // ** Below  Code to set the  screen to full screen 
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

My application uses  WiFi to get data from server,  so user must know whether he is connected  to WiFi by seeing the default WiFi icon of android, but the default WiFi icon is hided when the  UI is in full-screen mode I dont want the  wifi icon and  baterry icon to be hided, 
Is there any way to achieve or show the default WiFi icon and battery level icon  when the UI is in full screen mode

Comment: Can you please share the solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Part of going full screen is stripping all of this information away. That's part of the point. What you can do is check for [WiFi connectivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) and [Battery status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) and display the icons yourself. If you need icons you can use (and quite easily edit) the icons from the [Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20131106.zip) from Android (The same used for stock stuff).